# bookmark/watch button and hover text cloud with drupal module or css

Tags: css, drupal, button

I'm looking for some direction (working with Drupal core.)
I would like users to subscribe to various aspects of a node. For instance, to bookmark it for later viewing, or rate it as good or bad.

I would like the site to have a consistent theme, and would love for each of these features to use a button that is toggled on/off with js/ajax. Also, for instance, it would be great if the 'bookmark' button also included the number of other users who have bookmarked the same node. Exactly like stack overflows favorite star on the side. <---

Lastly, the button needs a text cloud, just like the image links I have included (thanks github)

http://www.trailspice.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/feature-button-description.png

http://www.trailspice.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/feature-valued-button.png

Does anyone know of a css stylesheet, or druapl module, which can help me get to this end? This is ultimatly they exact style I will be trying to-recreate, and I only bother asking because I have now seen it on a few website kickstarter.com for example, also uses a similar button for watching nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have users bookmark nodes, take a look at the [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag).  From the project page:

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by
>   the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can
>   provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, or users. Some
>   possibilities include bookmarks, marking important, friends, or flag
>   as offensive. With extensive views integration, you can create custom
>   lists of popular content or keep tabs on important content.

For users to be able to rate nodes, I would recommend the [Fivestar module](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar).  From the project page:

> The Fivestar voting module adds a clean, attractive voting widget to
>   nodes in Drupal 5 and 6. It features:
>
> - jQuery rollover effects and AJAX no-reload voting
> - Configurable star sets
> - Graceful degradation to an HTML rating form when JavaScript is
>     turned off
> - Support for anonymous voters
> - Spam protection to keep users from filling your DB with bogus votes
> - Easy-to-use integration with Views module for lists sorted by
>     rating, or filtered by min/max ratings
> - A Fivestar CCK field for use in custom node types
> - An easy-to-use Form API element type for use in other modules
> - Compatible with all versions of jQuery (1.0 - 1.3.2)

Both of these modules are very customizable and can use AJAX.  For the buttons to have a "cloud" (tool tip), see this ["jQuery tool tip" Google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery%20tooltip), there are plenty of them out there for you to use.  You won't find an all-in-one module for this, it will require a little work to make it exactly how you want it.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful - tool tip, that was the keyword I needed.